# 'Syn' is undefined in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, database

There is no problem when I only have first script, but when I have second script, I have this error 'Syn' is undefined. I found out that there is no ScriptManager and handler in my config. I tried to add in ScriptManager, but this error 
"Error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: The PageRequestManager cannot be initialized more than once." comes out. Please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#content1').load("http://fswsql279/ReportServer?%2fDepartment%2fSSC%2fInformation+Systems%2fMSC%2fAppAssets%2fSLMGauge&rs:Command=Render&rc:toolbar=false");
           //$('#content2').load("http://fswsql279/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fDepartment%2fSSC%2fInformation+Systems%2fMSC%2fAppAssets%2fMscviewAnalyst&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML4.0");
        })

    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#content2').load("http://fswsql279/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fDepartment%2fSSC%2fInformation+Systems%2fMSC%2fAppAssets%2fMscviewAnalyst&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=HTML4.0");
    })
    </script>
```